# Vue-multiselect how to make two input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

https://vue-multiselect.js.org/

Tell me, is it possible for one block to select a result, make 2 query fields

Comment: Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: My task is to make two input lines by changing @ search-change, but the result should open in the same window below them